# How can I deal with a bigot who's playing a murderhobo?

Tags: dnd-5e, problem-players

I'd like to half-vent, half-ask a question here.

I've been playing in a campaign at a local gaming cafe. Each mini-campaign is 5 weeks. This player in particular is rather new, which *may* explain some of his behavior. This is also not a child, but even if it were, it would still be annoying. Over the past 6 weeks (we recently started a new campaign) he has:

1: Talked incessantly about Nazism and forming a Nazi-like gang. I had to pull my Jew card to get him to stop.

2: Been a crazy, violent murderhobo throughout the campaign (his character is chaotic neutral, btw, if that matters). He killed some random guy in town and tried to kill the guards who questioned him, tried to kill a whole tavern, and tried to kill a PARTY MEMBER.

3: Has no knowledge of consequences! He tried to kill a guard and was surprised when the guard fought back. He tried to breathe fire at guards and was surprised when they clamped his character's mouth shut. He was shocked when it was declared his character was to be hung for his crimes.

In the current campaign, he decided to jump down a 150-foot-wall, was surprised when he took a crap ton of damage (the DM warned him about this and even did the "Are you sure?" line), and was surprised when he failed 3 death saves and his character died.

4: Talked about killing babies violently.

5: Tried to make a rather racist (against East Asians) character

The DM has only given him talking-tos, never anything else. I'm at a loss, because I love the DM and other players, it's just this specific player.

Comment: I fail to see a question here. Items 1 and 4 are rather concerning, however you are not the DM. You should mention to the DM that you have concerns or issues with the player/play style.

Comment: 3, 5, and (at many tables) much of 2 are pretty darn concerning, too. But, I do believe this is, fundamentally, a duplicate of one of a dozen "problem player" questions

Comment: I suggest that you take this kind of question [to a forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566) if the related questions do not give you some tools to handle this player.  Your problem strikes me as something like this: nobody else at the table seems to be bothered by the behavior as much as you are.  Is that a fair assessment?

Comment: If you happen to be in Germany: Number 1 is a crime and worth a call to the Verfassungsschutz, they *gladly* come to talk to the guy.

Comment: Now that's a title update!

Comment: what do the rest of the players and the DM think about this? Does it bother them too or are you the only one? Have you spoken with the DM about your concerns? Is there something restricting DM's ability to choose and kick players (e.g. the gaming shop's policy)?

Comment: @minnmass If there are a dozen problem player questions, it seems more fair to OP to close this question as a dupe of another question that is _actually open_ rather than to close it as a dupe of a question that is itself closed.

Comment: @Kirt: that was simply the closest duplicate I could find relatively quickly (especially the "truly problematic" part) and the answer is applicable here. I have no objections to linking to a better match if one is found (though I don't know how to change the linked question in the "closed" tag).

Comment: @minmass If someone wants to suggest an open dupe, I think anyone with a gold badge can reopen this, then close it again as a dupe of the better target.

Comment: @Kirt Not necessary, gold badgers can simply edit the dupe list.